# find elements by class name selenium python is not working for me

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

I want to get web elements with the same class name. I'll use those to take screenshots of elements for my application. I am using Selenium in Python for this purpose.

```
url = "https://www.pexels.com/search/happy/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "MediaCard_image__ljFAl")

print("**** Start *******")
print(elements.count)

for element in elements:
 print("1")
 print(element.text)

print("**** End *******")
```

output is:

```
**** Start *******

<built-in method count of list object at 0x00000250202F2000>
1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

**** End *******
```

I think `element.text` is empty, but why? There are many elements with this class name. Can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 2):

Your selecteors select the images which don't have any text.
You need to fetch its attribute `alt` which contains text about images:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.pexels.com/search/happy/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "MediaCard_image__ljFAl")

print("**** Start *******")

for element in elements:
 print(element.get_attribute("alt"))

print("**** End *******")
driver.quit() # Don't forget to quit drivers
```

Output:

```
**** Start *******
Free A Woman Lying on the Lap Stock Photo
Free Woman in White Crew Neck Shirt Holding Red and White Floral Heart Shaped Cake Stock Photo
Free Woman in Black Blazer Smiling With Mirror in the Table  Stock Photo
Free Happy young female with long hair in warm turtleneck and leather jacket enjoying sunny day with closed eyes on street Stock Photo
Free People Looking at Laptop Stock Photo
Free Woman Wearing Brown Wicker Hat Stock Photo
Free Side View Photo of Smiling Woman Carrying Her Baby Stock Photo
Free Monochrome Photo of Woman Smiling Stock Photo
Free Monochrome Photography of Person Laughing Stock Photo
Free Young African American female keeping hands on head while laughing with closed eyes on white background Stock Photo
Free Baby in White Onesie Holding Wooden Blocks Stock Photo
Free Woman Wearing White Turtleneck Sweater Stock Photo
Free Happy black woman laughing on street Stock Photo
Free Photo Of Children In The Water Stock Photo
Free Photo Of Women Doing Their Skincare  Stock Photo
Free Happy Father and Son Stock Photo
Free Happy Couple on Bed  Stock Photo
Free Friends in Pink Clothes Stock Photo
Free Young cheerful female in dress looking at camera with toothy smile near pond and mount under cloudy sky Stock Photo
Free Black woman with dog near window Stock Photo
Free Photo Of Woman Wearing Pink Hijab Stock Photo
Free Woman Holding White Flower Bouquet Stock Photo
Free Woman Smiling Stock Photo
Free From above of African American smiling children with father lying on cozy bed and having fun while enjoying morning together on weekend Stock Photo
**** End *******
```